# Counting Rectangles in Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

The matrix can be of any Size, but will always contain either 0 or 1.

You can take the size of matrix from user and can take values from user.

eg : Matrix :

```
1 1 1 1    
1 1 0 1    
1 1 1 1
```

The objective of this problem is to count rectangles in a matrix.

> The properties of rectangles are as follows:
>
> 1. The border of the rectangle consists of 1's only.
> 2. each rectangle needs to enclose at least one 0
>             e.g. There will be two rectangles in the above matrix.
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
> 3. A rectangle can contain multiple rectangles.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Two distinct rectangles can constitute a super rectangle.
>
>    [image]

Can anybody think of any algorithm to do so?

**Note:** Assume user has input correct values.

**[EDIT]:**

Just consider 1 as dots (.) and 0 as space (nothing).

Now you have to join all the adjacent dots and calculate the number of rectangles.

But each rectangle should contain atleast one space.

So the minimal submatrix will be 3X3.

Comment: you question still isn't very clear: The rectangles will always enclose some 0’s... that is very vague..

Comment: It means that the Rectangle [sub matrix] made up with 1's should contain atleast one 0 in that sub matrix. I hope it is much clear now.

Comment: a little more but not enough. You say "there will be two rectangles in above matrix"... I don't see them. Can you point them out?

Comment: I have updated my question. I have tried to point to the two rectangles, if it is much clear now.

Comment: What complexity are you aiming?

Comment: Complexity is not the concern. Firstly i want to deduce any algorithm that can be helpfull

Comment: Then you can try every rectangle (just choose 2 corners).

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head

```
1 1 1 1    
1 1 0 1    
1 1 1 1
```

+1 to every 1 that touches 0
in next iteration +2 to all that are touching non 1 
You should end up with something like this.

```
3 2 2 2    
3 2 0 2    
3 2 2 2
```

Comment: Still the problem remains same. Try taking an example with multiple 0s and multiple 1s. How to deduce the number of rectangles.